# Extracting Disqus comments from webpages using c#

Tags: c#, disqus

It is necessary for me to fetch user comments in each news page in CNN website, which uses [disqus](/questions/tagged/disqus) comment system. I have used [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) for html parsing. Is there any specific code which I can use in order to extract the commented author and the comment using [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Thanks in advance,
Dinusha

Comment: Have you any code that you tried yourself? And if you have one would you mind posting it?

Comment: I do not have any code at the moment. I've heard of DisqusSharp. But I could not find any examples of it in order to try some code.

Answer (score 3):

Since the Disqus embed is a javascript embed, the comments won't be available in the page source unless the site renders them there. If you're scraping the page and letting the javascript render, then the first page (up to 50 comments) are available within the Disqus iFrame within the "postCompatContainer" DIV.

However, I'd instead suggest using the Disqus API to accomplish this. There's two main parts to this:

1. **Get the thread information from the article**

Specifically in the page source you have to find the variables 'disqus_shortname' and 'disqus_identifier' or 'disqus_url'. If 'disqus_identifier' or 'disqus_url' aren't available, then you can try using the window location address, but this is less reliable.

1. **Make the API call with that data.**

Specifically you'll want to use our [threads/listPosts](http://disqus.com/api/docs/threads/listPosts/) endpoint passing the 'disqus_shortname' as the 'forum' and the identifier or url as 'thread=ident:' or 'thread=link:', respectively.

I won't go into the specifics of using the API here, but we have a good starter tutorial here: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1131783-tutorial-get-comment-counts-with-the-api

and more examples here: https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thank you very much for the reply. I am very new to this API. Can we use DisqusSharp for this purpose? If possible please provide a small sample code in c#. So I can begin my code with it.

Comment: DisqusSharp looks unsupported, and it uses our old API anyways. This is a C# sample that works in Windows Phone, so you might need to modify it a little bit: https://gist.github.com/ryanvalentin/5767814

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thank you very much for the sample code. I can start my code with this. I have developed a Windows Form application for extracting news articles as well as comments. It is necessary for me to extract comments from several websites in addition to CNN. When obtaining the API key what should I give for “Website”(Your application's website) information in the application form? Do I have to get separate keys for all sites which I am accessing?

Comment: That field is just for labeling purposes, so you can put whatever you'd like. You do have to put a "domain" further down if you plan on using any client-side scripts, but otherwise you'll simply use the secret key for server-side requests.

Comment: Hi Ryan, I was able to extract comment information by modifying your code according to my requirement. Thank you very much for the sample code. I encountered one issue. There are article URLs which consist " ' " (ex:nation.lk/edition/international/item/…). For such URLs when I use them as [thread= link:url] I do get the following error via the API. {"code": 2, "response": "Invalid argument, 'thread': Unable to find thread…} I even tried encoding the URL, but it did not work. Please advice.

Comment: That means the thread that was shown on that URL wasn't stored in Disqus with the same URL. There are many reasons for this (CNN can choose to have another link-to URL), but none of them are really in your control. Most sites use 'disqus_identifier' so check for that in the page source and query that with [thread=ident:...] if available.